# Efficient way to find maximum value of Sparse matrix (Eigen)

Tags: c++, eigen

I was wondering whether it is possible to find the max/min coefficients in a sparse matrix in an efficient way.

It seems that the minCoeff()/maxCoeff() functions are not implemented for sparse matrices, which is a bit weird.

I found this answer [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=151658#), but I could not figure it out.

```
 using Tmp = typename remove_cv_ref<decltype(matrix)>::type;
 if constexpr(std::is_base_of<Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Tmp>, Tmp>::value)
 max = Eigen::Map<const Vector>(matrix.valuePtr(), matrix.size()).maxCoeff();
 else
    max = matrix.maxCoeff();
```

**Edit:**
This is my try, I am not sure about the efficiency.

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<int, Eigen::RowMajor> SRI;
int maxCoeff(const SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> &A)
{
    size_t row = A.rows();
    size_t col = A.cols();
    int max_value = -10000000;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < row; k++)
    {
        for (SRI::InnerIterator it(A, k); it; ++it)
        {
            if (it.value() > max_value)
                max_value = it.value();
        }
    }
    return max_value;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those functions are not readily available because it might be ambiguous whether the implicit zeros should be taken into account or not. For instance, if all non-zeros are negative, shall `maxCoeff` returns `0`?

If you want to consider explicitly stored elements only and that your sparse matrix in is compressed mode, then you can write:

```
auto max = matrix.coeffs().maxCoeff();
```

The [coeff](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseCompressedBase.html#a7cf299e08d2a4f6d6869e631e51b12fe) method is equivalent to RHertel's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this templated function to obtain the maximum non-zero value of an `Eigen::SparseMatrix`:

```
template <class T>
T sparseMax (SparseMatrix<T>& mat) { 
  return Map<Matrix<T, Dynamic, 1> >(mat.valuePtr(), mat.nonZeros()).maxCoeff();
}
```

The principle here consists in mapping the non-zero elements of the sparse matrix onto a vector (a one-dimensional `Eigen::Matrix`) from which the maximum is then extracted with `.maxCoeff()`. This should be a very efficient means to determine the maximum value in the matrix.  Note that the **matrix needs to be compressed** for this method to work.

In the code, the function `sparseMax()` could be called like this:

```
if (!mat.isCompressed()) mat.makeCompressed();
auto max = sparseMax(mat);
```

where `mat` is an `Eigen::SparseMatrix`.

The answer in the link is thus almost correct, but`.size()` should be replaced with `.nonZeros()`  and it failed to ensure that the matrix is compressed. If you know that you are dealing with a SparseMatrix the `if/else` construction mentioned in the linked answer is not needed.

---

**Edit**

The above solution works for a SparseMatrix with the default column major storage order. In the case of RowMajor storage one could change the template to

```
template <class T>
 T sparseMax_RM (SparseMatrix<T,RowMajor>& mat) { 
 return Map<Matrix<T, Dynamic, 1> >(mat.valuePtr(), mat.nonZeros()).maxCoeff();
}
```

A more robust way is to use the member function `.coeffs()` instead, as pointed out by @ggael. The `.coeffs()` function works for compressed SparseMatrix classes of both types, RowMajor and ColMajor storage order.

Comment: Still wandering why they did not implement a function for this.

Comment: About "why", see my answer.

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to ‘sparseMax(Eigen::SparseMatrix<int, 1>&)’
     auto max = sparseMax(mat);` `template argument ‘1’ does not match ‘0’
     auto max = sparseMax(mat);`

Comment: @Abolfazl The error appears because you are using a SparseMatrix with `RowMajor` storage, instead of the default `ColMajor` order. To handle that special case one could change the template to `T sparseMax (SparseMatrix<T, RowMajor>& mat) `. Generalizing the answer in order to have a function that accepts both, `RowMajor` and `ColMajor` storage is unnecessary as the member function `.coeff()` seems to be doing exactly that.